How to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error
So just starting learning Java on my school.
However when I tried to open my Java project that I made on my school on my laptop at home, it gives error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException (image 1)
Image1
Image2
However, when I made a new project from scratch on my computer, it works fine (image 2)
Any suggestions how to fix this error?
Is it because of different eclipse version on both computers?
